# illegal start of type with for loop i can't resolve it

Tags: java, arrays, object, netbeans

```
  public class gass extends JFrame
{  
  Object[][][] data = new Object[100][100][100]; 
  String title[] ={"Box", "Weight", "Priority"};
        int i=0;
        int nb=100;
        int E1;
   for (i=0;i<nb;i++)
            {
                    E1 = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                    data[0][i][0] = E1;
            }  
   for (i=0;i<nb;i++)
              {       
                    E1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                     data[0][0][i] = E1;
              } 
}
```

I just want to fill the Object Array (data) with the following informations but it shows me the error message : 
illegal start of type
 expected
error: ';' expected (inside the loop)
and many other error and it's really confusing me !
could you help me ?
i tried to create a method as :

```
public void fillIt(){
    int i=0;
        int nb=100;
        int E1;
 for (i=0;i<nb;i++)
            {
                    E1 = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                    data[0][i][0] = E1;
            }  
              for (i=0;i<nb;i++)
              {       
                    E1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                     data[0][0][i] = E1;
              }     
}
```

but when i call it using :  `fillIt();` error: invalid method declaration; return type required
        fillIt();

Answer (score 2):

In java class you cannot write code/ executable statements outside the methods. Move your for loop code mentioned below in a method or constructor:

// this need to go in a method

```
   for (i=0;i<nb;i++)
            {
                    E1 = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                    data[0][i][0] = E1;
            }  
   for (i=0;i<nb;i++)
              {       
                    E1 = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                     data[0][0][i] = E1;
              }
```

Comment: but i tried to put that code inside the method 'public void fillIt()' as i mentioned than it wouldn't let me call it ..

Comment: @GhassenBellagha Can you share that complete code, because your fillIt method seems to be code.

Comment: The code is too long i will share a link to get to the full code cause am too new here :) 
[link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1geD26M6HBIJQDOuQdXW_0NXPfrmY75Ua9uBFPZz-bqI/edit?usp=sharing)
and thank you